# Why my light doesn't appear when I activate Cycles render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I add some objects and lights (I use area). Then I enabled display render preview using Eevee, and it work. But when I switch to Cycles render, the lights don't appear, I just saw my plane and some objects. Can someone help me solve this?

[image: With Eevee]
[image: With Cycles]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: sure, here is https://pasteall.org/blend/f147ca678d0f47f7ae6ed5e1dcee3846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of your lights, it's because of your plane material, its *Material Output* is set to *Eevee* instead of *All*:

[image]

Comment: OHH, got it, thank you very much, sir.